# Застревают очереди при отправке писем

Tags: laravel, очередь

Застревают очереди при отправки чере queue, если ставлю просто через send то отрабатывает стабильно

```
Mail::to($usermail, $username)->send(new \App\Mail\ConfirmEmail
```

Какие варианты решения этой проблемы существуют. Заранее благодарен.
Почтовый сервер exim

Проблема в том, что это задерживает отработку скрипта так как очередь работает прозрачно и на отработку скрипта никак не влияет, а при прямой отправке происходит задержка и довольно существенная так как отправка идет не одному адресату, а десятку или даже сотне

Драйвер Redis

Comment: поиск приводит к этой ссылке: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail , где написано что эти самые очереди ещё и настраивать как-то надо (ссылка на инструкцию там присутствует). думаю, именно к этому и относится ваш вопрос, а не к работе программы exim (намекаю, что метку стоит убрать).

Comment: Драйвер очереди какой? Параметр QUEUE_DRIVER в /config/queue.php

Comment: Так же не видно кода отслыки писем с использованием очередей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании QUEUE_DRIVER=database

Если создана таблица для сбора заданий завершенных с ошибками, там будет содержаться подробная информация.
Если не создана таблица выполните

```
    ./artisan queue:failed-table
    ./artisan migrate
```

Снова запустите listener

```
    ./artisan queue:work --queue=<название_очереди> --sleep=2 --tries=1 --timeout 30 --daemon
```

Выполните отправку сообщения и посмотрите есть ли не выполненные задания

```
    ./artisan queue:failed
```

Если будет такой вывод

```
    +----+------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------
    +
    | ID | Connection | Queue | Class                 | Failed At           
    |
    +----+------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------------
    +
    | 10 | database   | email | App\Jobs\SendEmailJob | 2017-04-11 11:43:16 
    |
    | 9  | database   | email | App\Jobs\SendEmailJob | 2017-04-11 11:40:16 
    |
```

выполните SQL запрос, в поле exception будет содержаться информация об ошибке.

```
   SELECT * FROM  failed_jobs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу как настроить очереди в Laravel т.к. непонятно - сделано это или нет.

Кнфигурируем:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

или

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

в env файле.

Если database то делаем:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```

Если redis, то ставим predis/predis

```
composer require "predis/predis ~1.0"
```

И redis server

[Процесс установки очень хорошо описан тут](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis)

Далее в консоли:

для database:

```
php artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

или

для redis:

```
php artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

Это будет работать пока вы не остановите нажатием ctrl + c

Самый лучший вариант [запуск слушателя под Supervisor'ом](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Для БД не рекомендуется запускать более одного процесса слушателя очереди. Т.к. возможны ошибки с блокировками таблиц.

Можно еще создать таблицу для неудавшихся задач:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate
```

в этой таблице можно будет увидеть исключение с которым завершилось неудавшееся задание.

Они будут доступны к перезапуску в дальнейшем:

```
php artisan queue:retry all
```

[Остальные команды](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#retrying-failed-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте эту ссылку [Easy and Fast Emails with Laravel 5.3 Mailables](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-and-fast-emails-with-laravel-5-3-mailables) я по этому примеру notification создавал, но queue еще не использовал.

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой! Оказалось сервер был внесен в черный спам список. Какой то анти-спам организацией. Видно прошлый хозяин изрядно отсылал спам. Отписал в их сапорт, объяснил ситуацию, попросил убрать из черного списка. С тех пор письма приходили как надо.

Comment: вообще не в тему, без очередей отправляется моментально, с очередью застревает

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае ошибка заключалась в том, что php artisan queue:work была запущена в консоли, внутри самого NetBeans. Как только запустил просто в консоли винды, то всё заработало.
P.s.: речь идёт о работе на localhost, операционка windows 10.